# JW player does not appear

Tags: javascript, html

head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

body

```
<div id="test">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("test").setup({                      // this is critical line
flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
file: "video.mp4",
height: 270,
width: 480
});
</script>
```

"jwplayer.js" and "player.swf" are in folder "jwplayer" which is in root.
"video.mp4" is in root directly.
div test appears on page, but player does not.
Firefox 16
Check in firebug console says:

```
ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined
jwplayer("test").setup({
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine to me. Have you looked at the networking tab of firebug? Make sure that jwplayer.js is loaded and not a 404.

[image: 404 sample]